# JavaScript replace literal line breaks with Unicode line break

Tags: javascript, utf-8

**How do I convert `\r` and `\n` to literal UTF-8 line break characters?**

In my code I serialize XHTML in to a string assigned to the variable `f`. Using `formData` (`fd.append('post_body',f);`) the line breaks (e.g. `\r` and `\n`) are converted in to literal characters for some reason. Here is what I'm experimenting with:

```
f = f.replace(/\r/gi,\u0A);
```

No frameworks.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you mean that the literal substrings backslash-r and backslash-n are appearing in your string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f = f.replace(/\r\n/gi, '\\u0A');
```

Comment: Your code works as far as I can tell; the problem is that `new formData` screws up line breaks (I've determined absolutely no resolute reasoning for it) and was forced to adjust my PHP code. Any way, thank you.